# R - Difference between two rows conditional on variables

Tags: r

Lately for everything I manage on my own, I feel like I have a point I need to clarify on this board. SO thanks in advance for your help.

The issue is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,3,4,5),
  Code_ID_Buy = c("100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","102D","102D","102D"),
  Code_ID_Sell = c("98C","99C","98C","99C","98C","96V","25A","25A","25A","25A"),
  Contract_Size = c(100,20,120,300,120,30,25,60,80,90,30,70,90,220,35,70,150,250,10,50,25)
)

Data<-Data[, totalcont := sum(Contract_Size), by=c("Code_ID_Buy","Month")]

View(Data)
```

I would like to calculate the difference in total contract size from one period to the next, does anybody know whether it is possible ? I have been working on that for weeks not finding the solution...

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve it

```
library(tidyverse)


library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,3,4,5),
  Code_ID_Buy = c("100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","100D","102D","102D","102D"),
  Code_ID_Sell = c("98C","99C","98C","99C","98C","96V","25A","25A","25A","25A"),
  Contract_Size = c(100,20,120,300,120,30,25,60,80,90)
)

Data %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(total_contract = sum(Contract_Size)) %>% 
  mutate(dif_contract = total_contract -lag(total_contract))
```

If you need to respect another variable do

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Code_ID_Buy,Month) %>% 
  summarise(total_contract = sum(Contract_Size)) %>%
  mutate(lag = total_contract -lag(total_contract))
```

If you need to maintain the current structure left_join may be right

```
result <- Data %>% 
  group_by(Code_ID_Buy,Month) %>% 
  summarise(total_contract = sum(Contract_Size)) %>%
  mutate(lag = total_contract -lag(total_contract))

Data %>% 
  left_join(result)
```

Comment: Yes @Bruno thank you a lot, I had been trying that and thanks to ```summarise(total_contract = sum(Contract_Size)) %>%``` somehow it works. Do you by any chance know why the following did not work ?
```Data<-Data[, totalcont := sum(Contract_Size), by=c("Code_ID_Buy","Month")]
Data %>% 
  group_by(Code_ID_Buy,Month) %>% 
   mutate(lag = totalcont  -lag(totalcont ))```

Also when I store this into Data and want to display it as a data frame, it seems to drop all of my other variables, is it due to the fact that it uses data tables here ?

Comment: Good question, summarize maintains only the values it creates and the grouping variables, I am not too proficient using data.table

Comment: added a left_join extension if you need to keep all variables